# Angular2: Retrieve FileReader result with a Promise

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, settimeout, filereader

On my view, there is an input file linked with one function of a controller

```
<input type="file" style="display: none;" (change)="importXML($event)">
```

This function call a function in a service which suppose to convert my xml file to a json

```
importXML(event): void {
        const obj = this.myService.convertXML2Json(event.target);
}
```

In the service function, the XML file is read in a FileReader and then converted
to xml in the onloadend part of the file reader

```
convertXML2Json(event): any {
    const file = event.files[0];
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onloadend = e => xmltoJsonFunction(fr.result);
    fr.readAsText(file)
}
```

How can I retrieve the converted json result inside onloadend to use it in the Angular controller, specifically with a Promise ? Or should I use a setTimeout ?

Answer (score 0):

Your result is not located inside `fr` object. Parameter `e` inside your callback function has the result of read file:

`fr.onloadevent = e => xmltoJsonFunction(e);`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a fix, if I code only on the controller part :

```
  public XMLParsed;

  importXML(event): void {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onloadend = (e: any) => {
        this.XMLParsed = xmlToJSON(e.target.result);
    };
    fr.readAsText(file);
```